# EcomDev_PHPUnit fixtures: set config XML attributes

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

Sometimes I need to set up config XML attributes for automated testing.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <somenode foo="bar" />
    </global>
</config>
```

I would like to define this as a fixture as the XML configuration is only needed for executing some tests. Is this possible with EcomDev_PHPUnit?

For now I'm working around the issue by executing this in my `setUp` method:

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('global/somenode')->addAttribute('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in a fixture file:

```
config_xml:
  global: |
     <somenode foo="bar" />
```

Comment: I managed to add an attribute like this, thanks. (And don't I don't get it to work now aynmore. No idea why.) I also need to add a child with a value to `somenode`. I couldn't do it by mixing XML and fixtures, using fixtures only with `config:` and `config_xml:` or using fixtures only using `config_xml:` with nested tags. I guess I'm doing something wrong. Do you know more about it?